# Tensorflow Keras: Can `Conv2d` layers now accept multispectral images meaning bands greater than 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have some 8-band satellite images and wanted to do some image segmentation with `Tensorflow` and `Keras`. I tried to do this a couple of years ago, but saw that `TF` and `Keras` could not handle images with bands greater than 3. However, I am seeing more blog posts about deep learning with multiband images.

In looking at the `Keras` documentation, it does not specifically list any problems with accepting multiband images. And I found this [code](https://github.com/reachsumit/deep-unet-for-satellite-image-segmentation/blob/master/unet_model_deeper.py) which seems to make it work:

```
def unet_model(n_classes=5, im_sz=320, n_channels=8, n_filters_start=32, growth_factor=2, upconv=True,
               class_weights=[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3]):
    droprate=0.25
    n_filters = n_filters_start
    inputs = Input((im_sz, im_sz, n_channels))
    #inputs = BatchNormalization()(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
pool1 = Dropout(droprate)(pool1)
```

So just wanted to clarify, can `tf.keras.Conv2d` layers and other layers accept 8 or more band images now? Are there any pitfalls of using multiband images--like needing some transformations on the data before processing. Are there any limitations on using multispectral images?

Comment: You are mistaken, Keras Conv2D layers have always been able to handle multichannel data, its a basic property of CNNs

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Oh that is great. For some reason I had it in my head that Keras could not do this, but thanks for setting me straight. Do you know of any good examples or documentation on using multispectral data? Do I need to do anything different than usual? I imagine if the shape of the image tensor goes in correctly, it should work right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the can accept more 8 channels. Both Keras and TensorFlow layers. The main problem with images that have more than 3 channels is that majority of readily accessible pre-trained models were trained on standard imagenet dimensions, like [299,299,3] In this case it will require considerable ammout of work to fine tune such model to your data. 
As a solution to this you can insert a special 'resizing' convolutional layer which will reshape it to 3 layers.

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(320,320,8)) 
resize = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size)(inputs)
```

This however, can cause some data loss so needs to be used with caution.

Comment: Okay, so that is making a lot more sense. I looked into it a couple years ago and what you say sounds familiar. The transfer learning piece was the issue. Phew, thanks so much. Okay, so as long as I put the image tensor into the layer properly, it should work.

Comment: Also if I am training multispectral data, then I don't need to push the images into the usual PNG integer range between `[0,255]` right--especially since I can't use pretrained imagenet data anyway. Or I could use imagenet weights to start, and at the same time preserve the larger integer range (u16) of TIFF files, etc.

Comment: Normalization is helpful anyway, besides, you can use pretrained models, you just need to make dimensions equal. Another approach is to create separate networks for different channel of your data, or concatenating several pretrained conv layers in parallel. Try different approaches and see what works. And don't forget data augmentation. In case you have at least 10K images and no large class imbalance, you can try to train from scratch, just choose right net architecture

Comment: Thanks so much. @Sharky. Yeah, I will definitely try the variants you suggested. I was really just trying to understand what was possible under the hood of `keras` and `tensorflow`. I am still just getting used to coding tensorflow, and in some cases it is hard to tell if error messages are about formatting something incorrectly (like the row x col x band order of an image tensor) versus trying to do something that is incompatible with `tensorflow` or `keras`. Thanks again.